# How can I get multiple histogram plots from a dataframe in Julia

Tags: dataframe, plot, julia, histogram, statsplots

I have a julia dataframe and I want to plot each column as a histogram, but only the last one is finally displayed.  I'm using StatsPlot.  Is there a better plotting package to use for this?

```
using StatsPlots
@df df histogram(:x1)
@df df histogram(:x2)
@df df histogram(:x3)
@df df histogram(:x4)
@df df histogram(:x5)
@df df histogram(:x6)
@df df histogram(:x7)
@df df histogram(:x8)
@df df histogram(:x9)
@df df histogram(:x10)
@df df histogram(:x11)
@df df histogram(:x12)
@df df histogram(:x13)
@df df histogram(:x14)
```

Comment: how do you want these histograms displayed: tiled or overlayed?

Comment: In separate windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Bogumil says in his comment it's not entirely clear what output you're after, but I can see two possible ways:

If you want to have a separate subplot for each column, you can broadcast the `histogram` call over the columns you want, example:

```
julia> using Plots, DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame([randn(1_000) .+ i for i ∈ 1:10], :auto);

julia> plot(histogram.(eachcol(df))...)
```

which gives

[image]

Alternatively if you want all the histograms overlaid you can use `histogram!` (note the bang) which modifies an existing plot:

```
julia> plot(); last(histogram!.(eachcol(df)))
```

[image]

Note that here I've called `plot()` first as every `histogram!` call overrides an existing (global) plot object, so if I had called this after creating the multiple-subplots version above the additional histograms would have been plotted on the existing previous plot.

Both of these suggestions are going for brevity and might make it harder to fine tune things like labels, titles, etc. and I often find loops a clearer way to write these things, but hopefully they give you an idea of how what you're after can be done relatively easily (and without `StatsPlots`, all of this is plain `Plots`)

Comment: The first one is what I want.  That works great in Jupyter, but it doesn't work at all in the repl.  (The repl was able to display a single plot earlier, but won't even do that any more.)  For use from the repl is there a way to save the plots in files?

Comment: For me the first solution produces the desired output in REPL also. What code exactly does fail for you? Here http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/output/ you have more information about displaying your plots and saving them to a file.